# How to return an Object from a loaded .dll file in powershell

Tags: powershell, dll, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to use a Powershell-script to build a connection with Microsoft Dynamics CRM.
In some others scripts I want to use this connection.
If I export the connection-object, I can't use it as connection-object.

I return the object with:

```
[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy] $connection = New-Object Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy($organizationUri,$null,$clientCredentials,$null)
[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity] $systemUser = $connection.Retrieve("systemuser", $userId, (New-Object Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.ColumnSet(@("firstname", "lastname"))))
return $connection
```

And this is, how I call the script above:

```
 [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy]$connection = (New-CRMConnection -server $connectionjson.server -organization $connectionjson.organization -domain $connectionjson.domain -user $connectionjson.username -password $connectionjson.password)
```

But I get this error (I translated it from german, so it's not the exact error-message):

```
The value "System.Object[]" from type "System.Object[]" cannot be converted to "Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy".
In C:\Users\drieke\Documents\git\SNC-CRM\Solution\Import-CRMSolution.ps1:19 Zeichen:5
+     [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy]$connection =  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

How do I correctly return my object?

**EDIT**

My problem was, that my function returned an array.
The first Object in the array is the object i need.
So my solution is the [1] in following code:

```
 [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy]$connection = (New-CRMConnection -server $connectionjson.server -organization $connectionjson.organization -domain $connectionjson.domain -user $connectionjson.username -password $connectionjson.password)[1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means that `New-CRMConnection` returns an array of objects. Conversion from array into some other non-collection object makes no sense, so Powershell complains.

To debug the scenario, first save `New-CRMConnection`'s return value into a variable and work from there.

```
$connections = (New-CRMConnection -server $connectionjson.server `
-organization $connectionjson.organization -domain $connectionjson.domain `
-user $connectionjson.username -password $connectionjson.password)

# What kind of object is connections?
$connections.GetType()

# If it was an array, let's see its 1st element    
$c = $connections[0]

# What kind of object is the first element?
$c.GetType()

# If it looks sensible, try casting
[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy]$connection = $c
```